# iOS - UIButton title disappeared

Tags: ios, uibutton

Strangely, and suddenly, for some UIButton the title disappeard.
This is the screenshot taken from IB[image]

And this is what I get in running:

[image]

Comment: Have you made any UI changes via code?

Comment: build --> clean, then build --> run

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
The problem is with auto layout: you have to ensure that object in IB are properly aligned one another.